# Xdebug doesn't stop at break points in Symfony project

Tags: php, symfony, phpstorm, xdebug

I'm using MAMP free version and PhpStorm
To enable Xdebug in MAMP I've modified 2 php.ini files accordingly to [this](https://dillieodigital.wordpress.com/2015/03/10/quick-tip-enabling-xdebug-in-mamp-for-osx/) tutorial:

> /Applications/MAMP/conf/php5.6.10/php.ini
>   /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/conf/php.ini

Now I'm able to use xdebug in some simple project by listening to PHP debug connections. However if I try to use it in Symfony project, xdebug just ignores break points.

Here is my configuration for Symfony project in PhpStorm:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**UPD: Added screenshot of xdebug configuration** 
[image]
[image]

**UPD2: Added path mappings**
[image]

Comment: 1) Show your xdebug section of `phpinfo()` output as captured via browser .. as (AFAIK) on Mac/Linux you may have separate php.ini files for Apache and CLI 2) What xdebug log has to say about it (configure in xdebug options in php.ini; make sure it picks up new settings and try to debug -- then see what it has to say) 3) maybe you need do perform some path mapping? (e.g. needed when you have symlinks in a path etc)

Comment: Try to set up `Use path mapping` in your third screenshot, you also have to specifically trigger the debugger when calling your page. Append `XDEBUG_SESSION=whatever` to the query parameters.

Comment: Did You try to put break point in `app_dev.php` or `app.php` at the beginning ?? Maybe You put break point in place where request is not hitting

Comment: @LazyOne I've added a screenshot of xdebug config

Comment: @LazyOne I'm not sure if it's necessary to use path mappings, because I don't use virtual machine. However I've tried to define mappings (added screenshot) but get the same result. It's strange because this problem occurs in symfony projects only.

Comment: @BorisGuéry I've tried to use path mapping, but got no result. What do you mean by "specifically trigger the debugger"? On my another pc, where I use Vagrantbox, I just click on "Start listening for Php deubug connections", set breakpoints in controller, and do the right api call.

Comment: @skowron-line No, I've put the breakpoints in a controller, and do the right request to trigger that controller.

Comment: @rvaliev 1) The screenshot shows only part of it .. hiding the most important for me values 2) Try some newer xdebug version (2.4 at least) 3) What xdebug log has to say 4) If no symlinks in the path and code is local then no mappings will be needed

Comment: @rvaliev depending on your xdebug configuration you should generally indicate to the PHP process to actually start the debugger. https://xdebug.org/docs/remote#browser_session

Comment: 5) You can place programmatic breakpoint into your code and see if it will trigger debug session: `xdebug_break();` 6) In any case -- xdebug log will help a lot -- it can tell if debug session is started at all or what else is happening.

Comment: @LazyOne just added the other part.

Comment: @rvaliev Thnx. Looks OK for me (especially if it's working for you in other projects). Now collect xdebug log and try suggestion with programmatic breakpoint.

Comment: @LazyOne unfortunately I wasn't able to find any xdebug logs. But I've encountered with interesting issue. If I use just a regular project, and add print_r(xdebug_get_code_coverage()); then I see as output an empty Array, which is a good thing, because Xdebug is enabled. However, if I try this code in Symfony project I get a fatal error, that xdebug_get_code_coverage() is not defined.

I use MAMP free version, and all my projects are stored in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs. For example my Symfony project (named as 'system') is located in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/system.``

Comment: When I'm in 'system' I run symfony's own built-in 'server' with command php bin/console server:start

Maybe it's the reason xdebug isn't working?

Comment: @rvaliev Nope. Unless it uses completely different php.ini. That's why you should collect your `phpinfo();` via browser using that project and not any other. About xdebug log -- https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_log

Comment: @LazyOne yeah indeed, there's also another php.ini in etc/php.ini. Thanks anyway ;)

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you to try chrome XDEBUG extension. It works fine for me
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xdebug-helper/eadndfjplgieldjbigjakmdgkmoaaaoc